# Calculating a diagonal line around a cylinder

Tags: geometry

Is there a way to calculate (or estimate) a diagonal line around the exterior of a cylinder given the dimensions in the image below.
Height is $60$, diameter is $12$. The line starts at a $45$ degree angle and loops around exactly once.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to find the length of this diagonal line?  Or its equation?

Comment: Equation would be nice to see how it's calculated.

Comment: the line is a screw line, its length is easily computed with Pythagoras if you cut the cylinder and have a rectangle.

Comment: if you want line to loop exactly once, i.e. the end point should be lined up with the starting point, you cant's fix the angle at 45. The length of the line will be $\sqrt{60^2+(12\pi)^2}$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In figure top right is for comparison of helix with angle $\gamma=45^o$ wich is for 1.6 revolution (figure a in bottom left) and angle $\gamma=32^o$ for one revolution(figure b on bottom left).We have:

$tan \gamma=\frac ab$

where a is the radius of the cylinder(here 12") and b is the lead of he helix. For one complete turn(revolution) we have:

$h=2\pi b$

here $h=60"$

Parametric equation of helix is:

$\begin{cases}x=a\cos t\\y=a\sin t \\z=bt\end{cases}$

where $t$ is the angle of turn which for one turn is $t=360^o=2\pi$ . The length of the helix can be found by following formula:

$$s=\int^B_A\sqrt {x'^2+y'^2+z'^2}$$

Or for one turn:

$$s=\int^{2\pi}_0\sqrt{a^2\sin^2 t+a^2\cos^2 t +b^2}dt$$

Finally:

$$s=2\pi\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

which gives

$s=\sqrt{60^2+(12\pi)^2}\approx 70.8"$

But for one turn the angle is not $45^o$ it is:

$tan \gamma=\frac{60}{12\pi}\Rightarrow \gamma \approx 58$

and for the angle you shown in your figure it is:

$\alpha\approx 90-58=32^0$

If you want $\alpha=45^o$ then we have $ \gamma=90-45=45^o$:

$tan 45^o=1=\frac {60}{n\cdot (12\pi)}\Rightarrow n\approx 1.6$

where n is number of turn. In this case the legth of helix is:

$s=1.6\times \sqrt{2\times (12\pi)^2}\approx 85.3"$